# CSS color media query

Tags: css, media-queries

Can some one explain to me in very simple terms what the `color` media feature does exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ‘color’ media feature describes the number of bits per color component of the output device. If the device is not a color device, the value is zero.

Comment: but what does that mean exactly?

Comment: we normally represent color with red green blue in display screen. the color means the bit needed to represent the red green blue

Comment: such as 8-bit color 16-bit color

Comment: what is the highest value possible?

Answer (score 0):

It determines the color bit level based on the device.

If you read through this link, you'll find that an 8-bit device representing Red/Green/Blue as 3/3/2 will return a value of 2, as the lowest value is returned. So it's not always going to be as straight forward as 16-bit.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#color

Off the top of my head I can't think of any real-world "wow" about this one...other than monochromatic vs color, or perhaps offering a better set of color for low end devices that only support the 216 web palette.